# Powershell: Transform TotalItemSize into INT

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Hi i'm writing a PS Script to cofront mailboxes size to a limit and to send an email to users when this limit is exceeded.

I've prepared the Size variable like this:

```
$Size=Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity $_.samaccountname | Select-Object @{n="TotalItemSize";e={($_.totalitemsize -split " \(")[0]}}
```

and i get something like:

```
"samaccountname"  @{TotalItemSize=1.991 GB}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to get rid of everything except 1.991 GB ?
2. Can i tranform this value into an INT?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look to `$a`

```
$a = (Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity jean-paul.blanc).TotalItemSize

$a | get-member
```

You can see that it contains a property value that is a `Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ByteQuantifiedSize`

Now have a look to [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.exchange.data.bytequantifiedsize_methods%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx), you can find the method you are looking for `Tobytes()` so you can write :

```
$a.value.ToBytes()
```

or in your case :

```
$size = (Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity "Your user identity").TotalItemSize.value.Tobytes()
```

---

Edited :

If you only have got the string let say "34.01 MB (35,666,338 bytes)"

You can rebuid localy the object using :

```
$a = [Microsoft.Exchange.Data.ByteQuantifiedSize]::parse("34.01 MB (35,666,338 bytes)")
```

Comment: what they don't tell you in the documentation is that this only works in an EMS shell.  If you try it in an implicit remoting session, or you use invoke-command against the Exchange management session it fails because you get back deserialized objects, and all the  methods are stripped off.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see anything about remoting or invoke-command in the question.

Comment: And I don't see anything that says it's running in and EMS shell. Invoke-Command isn't being used, but the posted script could just as easily be run in an implicit remoting session as an EMS shell, and these kinds of scripts tend to get run as scheduled tasks.  In that environment implicit remoting is frequently used to avoid having to install the Exchange management tools on the server and keep them updated to match the Exchange server patch levels.

Answer (score 2):

This will get you the size as an int:

```
$Size=
 Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity $_.samaccountname | 
 Select-Object -ExpandProperty totalitemsize

 $Size = $Size -replace '^.+\((.+\))','$1' -replace '\D' -as [int]
```

I'd use that, and then divide by 1GB if you want an int GB value.  Mailboxes with smaller sizes may be returned as MB or even KB.  It's easier to start with the actual byte count and do the conversion yourself than parse all the possible string formats that may be returned.

But if you set the IssueWarningQuota on the mailbox, the system will automatically start sending them an email once a day when they exceed that quota.

Edit: there are also object methods available for getting the byte counts in various formats (like ToBytes()). These work fine as long as you're in an actual EMS shell.  If you try to use the same script in an implicit remoting session it will fail because now you're working with deserialized objects, and you don't have those methods any more.  The string parsing method is not as "pure" as using the object methods, but it's portable between those environments.

Comment: Your solution didn't work for me, I used:
$size = [int64]($size -replace '^.+\(([\d\,]+).+$','$1' )

Or to answer the solution directly: $Size=Get-MailboxStatistics -Identity $_.samaccountname | Select-Object @{n="TotalItemSizeGB";e={[int64]($_.totalitemsize.value  -replace '^.+\(([\d\,]+).+$','$1' )/1GB}

Answer (score 0):

You can convert decimal to int (using rounding) by casting it as an `[int64]`:

```
[int64]$val = 1.991
```

Or if you want to round down you can use `[math`:

```
[math]::floor(1.991)
```